# Proof language A= { 0^i 1^j where j>(i mod 3), j ≥0 , i≥0} is regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

$A = \{0^i1^j \text{ where }j>(i \text{ mod }3), i \geqslant 0, j \geqslant 0\} $

I know that A is a regular language, since we can construct the DFA or the NFA, but i dont know how to construct it, Can somebody help me please? Thank you

Comment: First use the Pumping Lemma to see IF it is actually regular.

Comment: I'd just create a regular expression. (000*)00111(1*) plus two more subexpressions.

Comment: @VimForLife That's quite useless and a waste of time since it's regular. (How do I know? I draw a FSM in my head, and type a regular expression in my head).

Comment: @gnasher729 Make an answer?

Comment: @gnasher729 can you please draw it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is regular since it's the union of the following $3$ regular languages:

- $\{0^i 1^j : i \bmod{3} = 0, j > 0 \}$ for which a regular expression is $(000)^*11^*$.
- $\{0^i 1^j : i \bmod{3} = 1, j > 1 \}$ for which a regular expression is $(000)^*0111^*$.
- $\{0^i 1^j : i \bmod{3} = 2, j > 2 \}$ for which a regular expression is $(000)^*001111^*$.

A reguar expression for $A$ is then $E = (000)^*(1 + 011 + 00111)1^*$. You can now easily construct a NFA from $E$.

Comment: Thank you very much